# Exception has occurred: TclError how do i fix it?

Tags: tkinter, label, pack

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

upper = Frame(root)
upper.pack(side=TOP)
lower = Frame(root)
lower.pack(side=BOTTOM)

icon = Label(root, text='One', bg='red', fg='white')
icon.pack(upper, side=LEFT)
spacing = Label(root, bg='red')
spacing.pack(upper, side=RIGHT, fill=X)
fill = Label(root, text='Two', bg='green', fg='black')
fill.pack(lower, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

i try to do this code but it keeps coming up with:

Exception has occurred: TclError

bad option "-bd": must be -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side

how do i fix this?

Comment: why did you put upper in the pack? `icon.pack(upper, side=LEFT)`

Comment: Entire error code please. I cannot see where you have typed in `bd`.

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason you need to pack the widgets into something other than their parents, it's best just to use `Label(upper, ...)` instead of `Label(root, ...)` for the ones you want to `pack()` into `upper`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're trying to pack a widget inside another widget other than its parent. If that's the case, you must assign the frame to the `in_` parameter.

```
icon.pack(in_=upper, side=LEFT)
spacing.pack(in_=upper,side=RIGHT, fill=X)
fill.pack(in_=lower, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```